# fire angular pipe event when button is clicked

Tags: angular, filter, onclick, pipe

I want to implement angular 5 search pipe when the button is clicked.

I have a input box which will receive custom search value and it filters different keys values from array of objects. I have implemented angular pipe when typed input text, it searches but i want to trigger this action when user input and search button is clicked only. Is there anyway we could achieve this. I am stuck at implementing click event

itemsearch.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'itemsearch'
})
export class ItemsearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  public transform(value, keys: string, term: string) {

if (!term) {
  return value;
}
return (value || []).filter(item => keys.split(',').some(key => 
 item.hasOwnProperty(key) && new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(item[key])));
```

}
}

```
 itemcomponent.ts


<div *ngFor="let item of items | itemsearch:'name, age':query"> 
{{item.name}}
         {{item.age}} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worth a read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is remove the pipe operator from the `*ngFor` and move the logic into your component

component.ts

```
import { ItemsearchPipe } from ...

search() {
   // you can do whatever you want here, return the value or store it in a variable
   this.items = this.ItemsearchPipe.transform(value, keys, term); 
}
```

then in your html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
<button (click)="search()"></button>
```

when using the pipe operator it basically calls the pipe function on every value change, when you move the logic into your component you can control when the pipe function is called

Answer (score -1):

I make the sample to implement your idea.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ewarg

Hint: The var query in   should not be the same object which is binding to the search textbox. We should have another object for textbox mapping. After click on Search, bind the new value from search textbox to the 'query' object.

Magic!!!

Happy coding :D

Comment: @ Duy Doan I want to access the filtered/piped items array before rendering on UI. I was trying to access by instance of ItemsearchPipe but i am getting only object back not the values